# To check a password between 7 to 16 characters which does not contain three consecutive same numbers or alphabets

Tags: javascript

To check a password between 7 to 16 characters which does not contain three consecutive same numbers or alphabets
eg: The password should not contain aaa or 111

Comment: The question itself is not too bad – although you definitely should provide more information, e.g. a code example of what you've tried yourself so far. But why JavaScript? Ok, maybe to provide instant feedback. But you should definitely implement your password policies on the backend, too.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Please note: if you're managing passwords properly, there is NO REASON WHATSOEVER to limit your maximum length to 16, since you're going to hash it anyway. On a similar note, a minimum length of 7 means there are people that ARE going to use a 7 character password. Again, if you're hashing it, it's not a big deal, but I'd go for a lower bound of 10 and no upper bound.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
function validatePassword(pw) {
    if (pw.length < 7 || pw.length > 16) return false;
    var lastChar = pw.charAt(0);
    var maxCount = 1;
    for (var i = 1; i < pw.length; i++) {
        if (pw.charAt(i) == lastChar) maxCount++;
        else maxCount = 1;
        lastChar = pw.charAt(i);
        if (maxCount == 3) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```